# Scrum: task dependency and task for architecture design

Tags: architecture, task, scrum

I have some Scrum problems:

1. Task dependency: Most books I read seem like treating the tasks as independent from each other. One programmer tasks doesn't affect the other's one, thus can be run in parallel. How to deal with task which is depend on another one?
2. Task is based on story/feature/function: There are a lot of ground works before setting up the project, e.g. design the architecture, learning the architecture, framework etc. And most functional tasks are depend on this architecture work to be completed. That's Q1 problem. At this time, there will be only one programmer working on the architecture design, while the rest of the team don't have any assign task?

Please tell me how to tackle this problem. Thanks

Comment: yea, I try to, the problem is, some answers require me to spend a lot of time to do research in order to verify it. I always run out of time to verify the solution.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Tasks are the steps towards the goal of a user story, similar to steps in a recipe. In both cases there are dependencies what to do when and in what order. **The key is that the team talks about how to split things to work most efficient**. This is not one person's job, but the Scrum team's. This happens initially during sprint planning when user stories are tasked out (by the whole team), but also daily as work is being done (daily standup etc.).

The skill is not really about finding tasks with no inter-dependencies as much as it is to **minimize the dependencies and to organize things in an optimally for team efficiency**. This is the team's responsibility. A Scrum Master's job is to mentor them in this direction.

(2) **In Scrum** (agile) **you don't do architecture up front**. That doesn't mean there is no architecture work in agile. On the contrary, **architecture is done continuously throughout the whole project**. From the start there are loose concepts and containers of ideas how to do things, and later on in the project this shell is filled with concrete architecture, bit by bit as needed by the user stories being worked on.

With regards to learning, this is true in any case, agile or not. **In agile you learn the whole time**. Not upfront. In the first few sprints there might be much less user stories picked as the team needs to learn new technology and other things, but **the essential thing is that something shippable needs to be taken on every sprint**. This has several benefits because the team can try both architectural ideas as well as their skills harnessing a new technology. Over time, this alters and the team will have a pretty good idea what the overall architecture looks like and how the technology works to pick more user stories.

My last advice is to not take over any constraints from waterfall like Q1, milestones etc. that say architecture is done by then and then. This is counter-productive and will fail. Stay agile (or not)!

Comment: Regarding the point (2): we can always divide the task, but merging the code is the problem. The architecture design is for setting the direction on how to merging the code later, like providing suitable interface, or using certain framework. or perhaps on how to passing the event/message from one programmer to another.

Comment: I don't quite understand. What is the problem in practical terms? Speaking loosely, if you know how two things fit together (interface so other), add this first and each part should be possible to add independently. It needs to be made in such a way that it doesn't break existing things (build/tests), but provides new things to be added which increments the feature towards completion.

Comment: "add this first" shows dependency task dependency. Someone must created an interface before it can be shared, whereas others need to wait for this interface before they can use it, right?

Comment: It means two people agree upon some interface which helps them both to get started working on the two parts. For instance, say it's an API that must be used between two things. Add the interface to the code base and then one can work on the implementation independently from the other which mocks it while working on the client using it. There is in most cases no such blockers that someone idles while someone else works. Also, agile is teamwork so people are usually involved in what others do too.