# Scrum: task dependency and task for architecture design

Tags: architecture, task, scrum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scrum: task dependency and task for architecture design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433217/scrum-task-dependency-and-task-for-architecture-design)

I have some Scrum problems:

1. Task dependency: Most books I read seem like treating the tasks as independent from each other. One programmer tasks doesn't affect the other's one, thus can be run in parallel. How to deal with task which is depend on another one?
2. Task is based on story/feature/function: There are a lot of ground works needed to set up up the project, e.g. design the architecture, learning the architecture, framework etc. And most functional tasks are depend on this architecture work to be completed. That's Q1 problem. At this time, there will be only one programmer working on the architecture design, what about the rest of the team members? What should they do?

Please tell me how to tackle this problem. Thanks

Comment: please stop repeating your own questions unless you want your account suspended; if your question does not involve code, it is generally a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

For some tasks you must take dependencies into account.

You can complete some tasks independent of other tasks of others if you base completion of the task on the passing of unit tests.

When you are manning a project start with the architecture team, then a small team that builds a vertical to prove the architecture. When that is complete you add members to the team.

Comment: I agree.  Another take on it is that the early architecture is done before you get to the point of drawing up tasks etc.  In some schools of thought it's at that point that you can decide which methodology to use (Waterfall, SCRUM, etc).